# Creating a cone in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

If I compile this file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={-20}{-10},xtick={1,2},ztick={1,2},ymajorticks=false,
  axis lines=center,
  axis on top,
  domain=0:1,
  y domain=0:360,
  xmin=-.25, xmax=2.25,
  ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-.25, zmax=2.25, tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
  samples=10,samples y=90]
  \addplot3 [surf] ({x*(1+sin(y))},{x*cos(y)*sqrt(2)},{x*(1-sin(y))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

then I get this:

[image]

This is more or less what I want. However, as you can see, it looks as if the cone isn't closed; there is some sort of cut near the origin. I wonder if someone can tell me how to avoid this.

If I use the `mesh` option (that is, `\addplot3d[surf,mesh]`), there is no such cut, as you can see below, but it would be better if I could avoid that possibility.

[image]

Comment: A little experiment on the parameter shows that with `y domain=0:450` instead of `y domain=0:360` you can get the right result, though I have no idea why it behaves like this.

Comment: like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612373/how-to-draw-this-cone ?