# angle in a plane with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (ey) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (ez) at (0,1,0);
  \coordinate (ex) at (0,0,1);
  \begin{scope}[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)},scale=2]

  \def\xM{1.2}
  \def\yM{1.6}
  \def\zM{1.8}
  \def\ech{2}
  
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (X) at (\ech,0,0);
  \coordinate (Y) at (0,\ech,0);
  \coordinate (Z) at (0,0,\ech);
  \coordinate (Px) at (\xM,0,0);
  \coordinate (Py) at (0,\yM,0);
  \coordinate (Pz) at (0,0,\zM);
  \coordinate (M) at (\xM,\yM,\zM);
  \coordinate (H) at (\xM,\yM,0); 
  \coordinate (ey) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (ez) at (0,1,0);
  \coordinate (ex) at (0,0,1);
  
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above left] {$\vec{\imath}$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[below] {$\vec{\jmath}$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left] {$\vec{k}$};
    \draw (O) -- (X);
    \draw (O) -- (Y);
    \draw (O) -- (Z);
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Px) node[left] {$x$};
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Py) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Py);
    \draw[->,blue] (O) -- (H);
    \draw[blue] (M) -- node[right,black] {$z$} (H);
    \draw[blue] (M) -- node[above,black] {$r$} (Pz);
    
    \path (H) node[below right] {$H$};
    \path (M) node[above right] {$M$};
    \draw pic [draw,->,angle radius=0.5cm] {angle = X--O--H};
    \draw (23:1) node {$\theta$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

I am not satisfied with the angle theta. It doesn't seem in the plane (Oxy). Probably because it is a circle instead of an ellipse (I hope I am clear).
So is there a way to improve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `3d` library and the option

```
canvas is xy plane at z=0
```

that draws precisely in the horizontal plane.

If you want another suggestion I'd use the `quotes` library too, this way you can specify the angle label as `\draw` option.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,     % for 'canvas is ... plane at ...' options
                angles,
                quotes} % angle labels

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (ey) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (ez) at (0,1,0);
  \coordinate (ex) at (0,0,1);
  \begin{scope}[x={(ex)},y={(ey)},z={(ez)},scale=2]

  \def\xM{1.2}
  \def\yM{1.6}
  \def\zM{1.8}
  \def\ech{2}

  \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (X) at (\ech,0,0);
  \coordinate (Y) at (0,\ech,0);
  \coordinate (Z) at (0,0,\ech);
  \coordinate (Px) at (\xM,0,0);
  \coordinate (Py) at (0,\yM,0);
  \coordinate (Pz) at (0,0,\zM);
  \coordinate (M) at (\xM,\yM,\zM);
  \coordinate (H) at (\xM,\yM,0);
  \coordinate (ey) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (ez) at (0,1,0);
  \coordinate (ex) at (0,0,1);

  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[above left] {$\vec{\imath}$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[above] {$\vec{\jmath}$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[left] {$\vec{k}$};
    \draw (O) -- (X);
    \draw (O) -- (Y);
    \draw (O) -- (Z);
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Px) node[left] {$x$};
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Py) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[dashed] (H) -- (Py);
    \draw[->,blue] (O) -- (H);
    \draw[blue] (M) -- node[right,black] {$z$} (H);
    \draw[blue] (M) -- node[above,black] {$r$} (Pz);

    \path (H) node[below right] {$H$};
    \path (M) node[above right] {$M$};
    \draw pic [canvas is xy plane at z=0,% draws in the xy plane
               draw=red,->,angle radius=0.75cm,
               "$\theta$",               % angle label (requires quotes library)
               angle eccentricity=1.6    % angle position
              ] {angle = X--O--H};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angletheta{atan(\yM/\xM)} % rotation angle for OHM plane (theta)
    \draw pic [rotate around z=\angletheta,canvas is xz plane at y=0,% draws in the OHM plane
               draw=red,<-,angle radius=0.75cm,
               "$\varphi$",              % angle label (requires quotes library)
                angle eccentricity=0.7   % angle position
               ] {angle = M--H--O};
    %\draw (23:1) node {$\theta$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Juan. It's brilliant. So I have another question: is it possible to specify any plane? For instance, if I want an angle in the plane (OHM)?

Comment: @Didier, yes, it's possible. You need to compute the angle theta, and then rotate the axes accordingly. See my edit

Comment: Sorry, another question. Is there a way to definitely exchange x,y,z for a 3D figure (I have to do it for each figure, with a scope ...). Maybe with a tikset in the preamble?

Comment: Thank you @Juan. I hadn’t seen your answer for my first question. And for my second question, I forgot to say that, of course, I don’t want this exchange to modify my 2D figures

Comment: @Didier, take a look for example at this answer. There I define new x,y,z axes. You can create a style too with you axes and call it as tikzpicture option

Comment: I didn’t understand your answer. When I look at your code, I see the exact same lines as in my MWE (coordinate (ey), begin{scope},…). Maybe I missed something

Comment: @Didier, sorry, my fault. I forgot the link, but I was talking about **this** answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612373/how-to-draw-this-cone/612380#612380

Comment: Thank you @Juan. I will look at that

Comment: But the angle \varphi is equal to 90°...

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro, I know. Just an example :D

Comment: @Juan. I understand that angle eccentricity corresponds to the distance of the label. It seems that the label is placed in the "middle" of the angle. Is there another to modify the "angle positionning" of the label (so it is not exactly in the middle)?

Comment: @Didier, I don't think so. If you need to do that just place a node as the theta in your code.